# Dúvida sobre exceções e blocos try/catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Gostaria de saber qual o "modo correto" de se escrever um bloco try/catch:

```
async function ping() {
  try {
    undefined();
    return 'pong';
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fn ping:', error);
  }
}

async function chamar() {
  try {
    const resultado = await ping();
    console.log(resultado);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fn chamar:', error);
  }
}

chamar();
```

Output ao invocar uma função não definida dentro da função "ping" com try/catch:

```
fn ping: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Porém, quando não se usa try/catch na função ping, o resultado é o seguinte:

```
fn chamar: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Qual seria o modo correto visto que a função ping sempre será chamada dentro de um try/catch. Além disso, eu quero tratar todos os erros na função "chamar". Tem algum problema não usar try/catch em funções que já serão chamadas dentro de outro try/catch?

Comment: Cadê essa função `pong`? Além disso, tem algum motivo para você estar anotando essas funções com `async`?

Comment: O correto era função `ping`, sinto muito pelo erro. Eu enviei apenas um exemplo, mas no projeto eu vou usar as funções assíncronas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe correto ou errado nesse caso. Depende da sua necessidade. Em relação à linguagem, ambos estão corretos.

A diferença na saída se dá pelo fato de que, quando alguma exceção é lançado em JavaScript, o bloco `try` mais "próximo" *captura* a exceção. Desse modo, como o erro ocorreu dentro da função `ping`, se você tiver, logo acima do código que lança erro, um `try/catch`, este irá capturar o erro, já que é o que está mais próximo.

Se você remover esse `try/catch`, ele procura um outro mais acima, que no exemplo da pergunta é o `try/catch` da função `chamar`.

---

Nesse exemplo, pode-se dizer que o `try/catch` de `ping` é desnecessário, já que você está fazendo o *runtime* lançar `TypeError` de de propósito (que em tese deveria ser capturado por ferramentas no ambiente de desenvolvimento). No entanto, para capturar erros desse tipo, que eventualmente podem passar despercebidos, é sempre ideal ter um `try/catch` "global", próximo ao *entry-point* do seu código, que lidará com exceções não tratadas.

Nesse caso, pode-se dizer que o *entry-point* do seu código é a função `chamar`, e o `try/catch` dentro dela está fazendo o papel desse *global error handler*.

Geralmente, utiliza-se `try/catch` em códigos "mais profundos" (como em `ping`) quando você chama alguma função ou realiza alguma operação que *pode* lançar alguma exceção. Por exemplo, ao ler um arquivo, executar uma *query* em banco de dados, etc. Desse modo, é ideal que você tenha um tratamento de exceção bem específico para a operação que você está fazendo.

É interessante ressaltar o contraste entre o tratamento de erro específico (tratado no parágrafo anterior) e o tratamento de erro global, que é bem mais genérico.

Leia mais sobre blocos [`try/catch` na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).